# Find a given four-digit word from a set of characters of the English alphabet

Tags: c#, stream

help me understand the task and if it is not difficult, could you tell me how I could do it, I do not ask you to completely decide for me, just show me the way. Task: Find a given four-digit word from the set of characters of the English alphabet. Each character is defined by a separate generated stream. I would be very grateful.

Comment: `set of characters of the English alphabet` is a string? Can you show some example of input and output? And also the code you written to solve this problem?

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly I needed to do. I did the following (the code below, it is written in c++ because it is more familiar to me), but this is wrong, because I somehow have to enter 4 characters, which will be determined by separate threads and the result is whether this word is in the specified set of characters or not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're telling us, I *think* perhaps the goal is to find "permutations" (of your input characters) that match "actual words".

Specifically:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/
>
> A permutation, also called an “arrangement number” or “order,” is a
> rearrangement of the elements of an ordered list S into a one-to-one
> correspondence with S itself. A string of length n has n! permutation.
>
> Source: [Mathword](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html)
>
> Below are the permutations of string `ABC`:
>
> `ABC ACB BAC BCA CBA CAB`

Your program might do the following:

1. Build a list of "English words"
2. Read "characters" from the stream
3. Generate permutations
4. For each permutation:

   - Search through the list of English words
   - Check if the current permutation corresponds to the next word in your list
   - If it does, print the permutation and the word

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to do it.